# Import and change colours of a "dissolved" Photoshop image in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, raster

I have an object with dissolved edges in Photoshop that I want to put into Illustrator as a shape or path.

Can I make an embedded dissolved object change colour like a normal shape in Illustrator?

If I live-trace the image, the shape doesn't come out like what I want or becomes too solid. Could you guys help to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The dissolve effect you have in Photoshop is a raster effect, it is made of pixels. There is no path data so you can't simply import it in to Illustrator as a vector object. Either:

1. Save your dissolved object as a *grayscale* image and place in Illustrator. As long as the image is saved in grayscale you can simply select the image and change the color just as you would with any vector object.

   [image: Changing color of a grayscale image]

   or...
2. Use Illustrator's Image Trace. There are a lot of options you can change on the Image Trace panel that should get you a result close to the original. You can see the difference between the original and the trace here:

   [image: Image Trace a dissolve effect]